# Export a raster layer with vector layer on top as a single JPEG image using PyQGIS?

Tags: raster, pyqgis, shapefile

I simply need to load on QGIS a raster and a vector layer, and then I want to export a map where both of them are displayed, in particular with the vector layer on top of the raster one. This because the vector layer is a polygon and is a sort of "mask" for the raster image.

In other words I want to perform with python code the same thing I do from the QGIS GUI going on **Project -> Import/Export -> Export Map As Image** when I have my two layers selected on the map.
I already tried this code:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsMapRendererJob, QgsMapSettings
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter
import os

layer_raster = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("RUKHO")[0]
layer_shapefile = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("mask")[0] 

width = layer_raster.width()
height = layer_raster.height()
image_size = QSize(width, height)

image = QImage(image_size, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
color = QColor(255,255,255,0)
image.fill(color.rgba())

p = QPainter()
p.begin(image)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setLayers([layer_raster, layer_shapefile])
ms.setOutputSize(image_size)

rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
ms.setExtent(rect)

#ms.setExtent(layer_raster.extent())

render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(ms, p)
render.renderSynchronously()
render.start()
render.waitForFinished()
p.end()

output_file = "C:/Users/borri/Master Thesis/ciao.jpeg"  
image.save(output_file, "jpeg")
```

I obtain a full white image

If I change the "extent part using the commented line and commenting the others:

```
# rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
# rect.scale(1.1)
# ms.setExtent(rect)

ms.setExtent(layer_raster.extent())
```

Then my QGIS app crashes and it closes without any message, not creating any image as output.

I thought about putting "layer_raster.extent()" only because I want an output with the same size as the raster layer.

I also tried something with the mapCanvas but the result is useless again. I thought that the line

```
ms.setLayers([layer_raster, layer_shapefile])
```

should tell which layers I want to export. But it seems not to be like that because with other tries I obtained an image showing ONLY the raster layer, without the vector on top.

Please help me I only found solutions with codes that don't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix your code is to take the `QgsMapSettings` object from the current project canvas.

Here is the code that works for me in the python console in QGIS:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsMapRendererJob, QgsMapSettings
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPainter
import os

layer_raster = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("RUKHO")[0]
layer_shapefile = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("mask")[0] 

width = layer_raster.width()
height = layer_raster.height()
image_size = QSize(width, height)

image = QImage(image_size, QImage.Format_ARGB32)
color = QColor(255,255,255,0)
image.fill(color.rgb())

p = QPainter()
p.begin(image)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()

ms = canvas.mapSettings()
ms.setOutputSize(image_size)

rect = QgsRectangle(ms.fullExtent())
rect.scale(1.1)
ms.setExtent(rect)

render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(ms, p)
render.renderSynchronously()
render.start()
render.waitForFinished()
p.end()

output_file = "C:/Users/borri/Master Thesis/ciao.jpeg"  
image.save(output_file, "jpeg")
```

Lines that fix the problem:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
ms = canvas.mapSettings()
```

Instead of:

```
ms = QgsMapSettings()
ms.setLayers([layer_raster, layer_shapefile])
```

Layers do not need to be added because they are open in your project. And they are on the current canvas.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very very much!